# Search by view count of youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to filter the videos which have more than 1000 only. I've the API call i've used to fetch the data.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=10&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2016-03-31T00:00:00Z&publishedBefore=2016-04-06T02:00:00Z&key={API KEY}

This returns all the videos which has been added 7 days ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should consult the documentation it appears that you can sort by view count but you cant restrict it by view count.   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters

Comment: @DaImTo : oh that means i can't filter the views more than 1000 ?

Comment: it means you cant search for videos that have more then 1000 views.

Comment: @DaImTo : my bad thanks for the information mate.

Comment: Ordr by viewCount then check views on your end.